# JavaFX threads shutdown upon application exit

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I wonder if there is any neat and clean way of shutting down my application's thread executors when the main window closes.

If the threads are marked as daemon threads they are automatically interrupted when the application closes. But in my case I do not want to do that. if a task is writing a file I want the task to finish and the thread to shutdown only after the task has finished, otehrwise I end up with a corrupted file.

A possible solution could be using each executor only once and calling shutdown on it after submiting the task, but that has the overhead of having to create a new thread each time a new task is to be submitted.

In my current application having just one controller I am using the onClose event of the main window to call a method in the controller to shutdown the executor if there is one (code below). But that is not a clean solution if there are many controllers.

```
MainController controller = loader.getController();
stage.setOnCloseRequest(ev -> {
    controller.finalize();
});
```

Can anyone devise a better one?

Comment: If there are many controllers, shouldn't they share the same executor anyway?

Comment: Good point @James_D, but I am asking what if I need more than one. Once I devised a terrible application wich used a thread pool to download data from several urls but needed to have just one thread to write the results or it would mess up their sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `stop` and call `shutdown` on your executor service;

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CleanExecShutdown extends Application {

    private ExecutorService exec ;
    private int count ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ListView<String> completedTasks = new ListView<>();
        Button button = new Button("Start new task");
        Random rng = new Random();
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            final int n = ++count;
            Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(rng.nextInt(1000)+1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                        exc.printStackTrace();
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    String message = "Task "+n+" completed";
                    System.out.println(message);
                    return message ;
                }
            };
            task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> completedTasks.getItems().add(task.getValue()));
            exec.execute(task);
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(completedTasks);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(button, new Insets(5));
        root.setBottom(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (exec != null) {
            exec.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(Obviously you need to refactor that if you have your executor in another class, but the idea is basically the same.)

Comment: That does almost the same I am doing althoug a bit better. But what if I end up having several executors in several controllers and subcontrollers? It can be done with each controller shutting down itself and it's subcontrollers, but is there any better way....?

Comment: Typically I would actually have each controller share the same executor; kind of the point of an executor is that it's a centralized mechanism for handling a thread pool. (So usually my executor is part of a service associated with a model, and the model is shared by the controllers, etc.) Then I call a shutdown method in the service (or model, depending the details of the architecture).

Comment: Yes, probably creating my own executor factory wich keeps track of the executors I will eventually need and knowing how to shut them down will be the neatest way. Thank you.

Comment: In the end, if you have multiple executors, you're going to have to call `shutdown` on each of them somehow. If you use a DI framework (e.g. `Spring`) to manage your controllers, you might be able to automate it by, say, making the controllers implement `AutoClosable` and implementing their `close()` methods to shutdown their executor(s). Then, if you use Spring to create the controllers etc, all your `stop` method needs to do is shutdown the spring bean factory. (Your executor factory is essentially a small-scale handmade version of that idea.)